# SQL Server 2014 trigger across multiple databases

Tags: sql, database, triggers, sql-server-2014

I have 2 databases `test1` and `test2`. Let's say that I have a system, that updates specific values in database `test1`.

Now I want to create a trigger which is placed in database `test2` to check if database `test1` updates the values.

When it is updated, I want to write something to database `test2`.

I have tried it with the following trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[testtrigger] 
ON [test2].[dbo].[naam2]
AFTER UPDATE ON [test1].[dbo].[naam]
```

However, I get a syntax error at:

> Incorrect syntax near 'ON'. Expecting ',',AS,NOT_FOR, or WITH

Now I wonder why this is happening. I have searched about how to do this, and the all reference to `ON`.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014

I will add a image to try and make it more clear if it isn't.
[image: Image of the 2 databases]

Comment: You cannot do this - the trigger always has to be where the action happens - you cannot have a trigger that "observes" another table - the trigger is fired when an insert, update or delete happens on the table that the trigger is defined on.

Answer (score 1):

> trigger is in database test2,when a table in database test1 changes,iwant to respond..

Your syntax is wrong..Below is overview of how you can do it

```
create trigger triggername on test1.dbo.table1
after update
as

begin
insert into test2.dbo.table2
select * from deleted

end
```

Comment: What i did: 

  **USE [test1].[dbo].[naam]
GO

create trigger ON [test1].[dbo].[naam]
after update
as

begin
insert into [test2].[dbo].[naam2]
select * from deleted

end**

Result is that it still gives the error at **ON**.  Expecting ID or Quoted_ID

Comment: i missed triggername,also your syntax is not valid,,use just databasename

Comment: Okay, that is working. However, it makes the trigger in database **test1**. My goal is to keep the trigger inside database **test2** so that database test1 does not have any triggers. I want the **test2** database to check if the **test1** database has any updates.

Comment: trigger won't work like that,you can write custom logic and compare

Comment: Because the whole problem is. We have a application, and we are writing a trigger that throws data to an other database. However, when we update it manual (Via SQL) the Trigger works. However, when we let the system do it (Wich put an update every 5 minutes in the database) it does nothing. The whole application actually stops with updating inside the database.       
So i had the idea to put the trigger inside the other database, in the hope that it would work.